# pattern restriction in substring- Python

Tags: python, list, substring

I found a question in glassdoor. I do not have additional clarification

Input : an int array [1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1]
you have to come up with a program that will give all possible subsets of the array based on the pattern.
Pattern restrictions were the string array should start with 1 and end with 1. So there will be many sub arrays like from index 0 to 3 and 0 to 4 and index 7 to 9

To solve this I was thinking of using 2 for loops and if both cases the values are equal to 1 then print them.

v=[1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1]

```
resultList=[]

for i in range(0,len(v)-1):
    for j in range(i+1, len(v)):
        if v[i]==1 and v[j]==1:
            r=v[i:j]
            resultList.append(r)

print(resultList)
```

Output:`[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1], [1, 1, 0, 0],`

I only see 1 correct value so far in output [1, 0, 0, 1]. Should I have used set instead of list? I tried that but that approach did not work either. Can someone kindly give some directions on how to solve this problem?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.combinations` to pick 2 indices where the values are non-zeroes in the list:

```
from itertools import combinations
a = [1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1]
[a[i: j + 1] for i, j in combinations((i for i, n in enumerate(a) if n), 2)]
```

This returns:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The probelm is in v[i:j]. Change v[i:j] to v[i:j+1]